# Bluetooth HC-05 module - why are there two COM ports?

Tags: arduino, hc-05

Why are there two COM ports after connecting the Bluetooth HC-05 module to my PC running on WIN10?

See this image from device manager:

[image: 1]

For sending data I use only one of them but I have to check it before which is correct. I have no idea what the second is used for.

Any idea?

Comment: This question would get a better, faster answer on [the Arduino forums](https://forum.arduino.cc)

Comment: One COM port *might* be RX while the other *might* be TX

Comment: @Rojo: I've tested that and it doesn't look like RX/TX because I can both send and receive data on one of those ports.

Answer (score 1):

This answer in [Microsoft Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/58f690e5-1939-43c2-a2d3-245a527c678b/bluetooth-serial-port-settings-for-windows10-pc?forum=win10itprohardware) sounds good:

> - when connecting your terminal program to the first you are actually instructing Windows to attempt to establish the Bluetooth connection
>   to the remote paired device, and if the connection is established the
>   RFCOMM channel will be opened for the exchange of data
> - when connecting your terminal program to the second you are actually instructing Windows to load the SPP SDP record and to remain waiting
>   for incoming connections from the remote paired device.